# Multiple equal testing for arbitrary length of a List[str] to solve LongestCommonPrefix

Tags: python

I am working on [Longest Common Prefix - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-prefix/solution/)

> Write a function to find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings.
>
> If there is no common prefix, return an empty string `""`.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```py
> Input: ["flower","flow","flight"]
> Output: "fl"
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```py
> Input: ["dog","racecar","car"]
> Explanation: There is no common prefix among the input strings.
> ```
>
> **Note:**
>
> All given inputs are in lowercase letters `a-z`

I design such a solution

```
def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:
    res = ''
    #base case 1
    if len(strs) < 1: return res
    size = min(len(s) for s in strs)
    #base case 2 one of them is empty 
    if size < 1: return res 

    #iteration case 
    for i in range(size):
        if strs[0][i] == strs[1][i] == str[2][i]:
            res += strs[0][i]
        else: break
```

if `if strs[0][i] == strs[1][i] == strs[2][i]:` add the element to `res`

However, in my solution,the length of strs is fixed as three, the given condition is a arbitrary length of strs

How could write such an expression like

```
            if strs[0][i] == strs[1][i] == str[s2][i] ....strs[length-1][i]:
```

`for else` solution:

```
    #iteration case 
    for i in range(size):
        prefix = strs[0][i]
        for j in range(1, len(strs)): #check the chain equal 
            if strs[j][i] != prefix: break 
        else:
            res += prefix

    return res
```

Comment: by the way, you shoud add `range` to `for i in len(size):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve that by `all` and `zip`, try this:

`if all(str1[i] == str2[i] for str1, str2 in zip(strs[:-1], strs[1:])):`

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Comment: thank you, I find that `for else` is also appropriate for such a situation. append it to  the end of question.